# events between threads and sub threads

Tags: c#, events, .net-4.0

I have a class that is multi-threaded.
in one function I fire an event, and those who were registered acted as expected.

Now the code has recently changed : the one function that fired the event has opened new thread (that after couple of steps should fire that event and not the parent function).

I see in logs that the event is fired but none of the registered listener react.

Is there any restriction on events between threads here? I wonder what we've missed here.

Comment: It would really help if you'd show a short but complete program demonstrating the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It´s really kind of guessing, but are you sure that ...

a) the listeners have **really** registered ...
b) to the **correct** event...
c) of the **correct** instance?

Try to ensure this through further log entries...